# Import product images from external url

Tags: magento-1.7, import

I want to import product images from external url in default import section (not in dataflow).
I have already tried http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/

Comment: Did you see the comment below that from Jaro explaining a change for 1.7

Comment: You can use our commercial extension Improved Import for import product images from external URL http://firebearstudio.com/improved-import.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible in default Magento. I suggest you add a preprocessing step which downloads the files into /media/import/.

Comment: Can you please tell me how and where?

Comment: For example, you could add a bash script using wget. Or you could create a PHP script which can be called on the shell which downloads the files using Zend_Http_Request. Or use any other programming language.
Personally, I'd use FastSimpleImport (http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/) and include that in a Magento PHP script. FastSimpleImport can download images on the fly if you provide the URL in the `_media_image` field.
If you are no developer, you can either hire one or download the image files manually into media/import/.