# Access product-images from external url

Tags: magento2, product-images, external-images

I need to display images for products without uploading on my server. I need to achieve:

1. Images are uploaded on another server
2. Images to be display on magento2 products

Is it possible that we add **ONLY URL of images** and it displays in Magento 2.  This is how we add product in Amazon like site by mentioning url of images.

What I already checked: [How to set product images from external url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/122708/29175), [Import product images from external url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/56483/29175)

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Heyy!! did you solve this issue? Can you please share findings?

Comment: This thing is not possible to display images from external resources in magento so we drop the idea.

Comment: It is possible https://magecomp.com/magento-2-amazon-s3.html
If you want to try,

Answer (score 2):

I think this is possible by using external server like AWS S3 and CloudFront to cache the images, then you can upload your images directly on AWS S3.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I dont think it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS S3 bucket to store all media files ( images, static files i.e css,js etc ). Whatever you upload ( product images, wysiwyg images ) from magento admin it will be uploaded on S3 bucket.

To achieve this you have to use and configure Thai's S3 Storage extension ( https://github.com/thaiphan/magento-s3 ).

After installation and configuring extension correctly, you will find a new option "Amazon S3" in "**Storage Configuration for Media**" under :

> Stores > System > Configurations > Advanced > System

```
Select "Amazon S3" , save settings and flush cache.
```

Once everything is setup you are good to go now. You don't need to do any changes in templates, your all product, category and wysiwyg images will be stored on S3 and will be rendered on front-end from bucket.

Comment: Seems interesting. Will try in free time some-day. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: it is extension for Magento 1, author asked about Magento2.